# Redux state not updating when action dispatched from a non-react file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am implementing react-bootstrap-table-next and need to get the clicked header column value to send to the database to sort it on the server side. I want to pass the clicked column name to the redux store. I can get the value clicked logged in actions but my state doesnt update inside redux.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../../reducers/index';

const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__; // eslint-disable-line
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);    
const columnClick = dataField => (event) => {
  const action = sortColName(dataField);
  store.dispatch(action);
};

export const columns = [
  {
    dataField: 'name',
    text: 'Name',
    headerEvents: {
      onClick: columnClick('name'),
    },
  }, {
    dataField: 'address',
    text: 'Address',
  }, {
    dataField: 'type',
    text: 'Type',
  }, {
    dataField: 'account_name',
    text: 'Account Name',
  }, {
    dataField: 'environment',
    text: 'Environment',
  }];
```

**This is my action.**

```
export const sortColName = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.SORT_COL_NAME,
    data: event,
  };
};
```

**This is my reducer.**

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from '../consts/action_types';

const initialState = {
  sortColName: '',
};

export const getSortColName = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.SORT_COL_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        sortColName: action.data,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**This is my store.js**

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export const configureStore = (history, initState) => {
  const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument(axios), logger, routerMiddleware(history)];
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)),
  );
  return store;
};
```

I get an error when I run this saying window is not defined.

I connect the reducer to the main index.js file using combineReducers and get the value in my component using mapStateToProps but state doesnt update.

Comment: you need to dispatch your action.

Answer (score 0):

Once created, you need to dispatch the action to a redux store. Like so:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'

store = createStore(reducer, initialState)

const columnClick = dataField => () => {
  const action = sortColName(dataField);
  store.dispatch(action) // <-- MISSING LINE
};
```

This will update the store's state & notify subscribed components.

Comment: I have 3 files here. The main file which contains the columns doesnt have anything related to store. So the above code should be placed in my reducers or the js file where I create my columns?

Comment: Action needs to be dispatched on an event. You can refer full example about react-redux [here](https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3)

Comment: @ashton I did it. Still I dont see the value in the store through the redux dev tools but gets console logged in the reducer